# How to get the currently selected option of a dom modified select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, select

I'm using a fake select box in my script which means the original select box is hidden and for styling purposes a ul is showing up. Whenever the selected value of this list changes the orginal select box does too.

There is a change function for that. Within that function is following code:

```
var el = $(e.currentTarget) ;
$('#my_select_box').children().removeAttr('selected');
$('#my_select_box  option[value="'+el.attr('data-value')+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

After that change I want to retrieve the new selected value of the original select box in another function.

But the normal selector only gets the original value, not the new:

```
$('#my_select_box option:selected').val() //returns the wrong value
```

So how to I get the new value in the function I need it?

I tried this function:

```
$("#my_select_box").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    console.log($(this).find('option:selected').val());    
});
```

It returns the correct value but not where I need it. So how can I retrieve the correct select box value out of the domtree live?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding a js fiddle can get your answer fast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of **.attr('selected','selected');**, try **.prop('selected', true);**

Comment: thx, but that's not the point. The selected option in the domtree changes. I checked that in firebug. The problem is just that I don't get the value of the dom tree modified element. I get the old value.

Comment: Oh wait! That actually did the job. Thank you! :)